# Refresh ListView with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm parsing a web service to display in a listView backed by my own subclass of ArrayAdapter. The data is `static ArrayList<Wait>` in `Application.java`. You'll see it referenced by `App.getWaits()`.

I use a simple refresh method for when there's new data. I've confirmed that it's being updated but it only renders if I navigate away and then return to the view.

In the past I've been able to refresh the listView by calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter but right now none of these have worked for me. Thanks for taking a look... any ideas!?

```
//1 This is how I'd normally update the listView dynamically, but not tonight.
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//2 It's the same thing really, so no good.
((WaitAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

//3 Saw this as the answer to a similar question, doesn't work.
adapter.getWaits().clear();
adapter.getWaits().addAll(App.getWaits());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//4 Called in onCreate but tried a 2nd time in refresh() to manually reset adapter, doesn't work.
adapter = new WaitAdapter(getHost().getApplicationContext(), App.getWaits());
list.setAdapter(adapter);

//5 Kinda the same thing, new adapter, reset adapter... also no good.
WaitAdapter adapter = new WaitAdapter(getHost().getApplicationContext(), App.getWaits());
list.setAdapter(adapter);

//6 I read ArrayAdapter keeps its own reference to initial data object but this fails too.
adapter = null;
adapter = new WaitAdapter(getHost().getApplicationContext(), App.getWaits());
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*Update to share my `WaitAdapter.java`.

```
public class WaitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Wait> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Wait> waits;

    public WaitAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Wait> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_wait, data);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        waits = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_wait, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.checkpointName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkpointName);
            holder.delayAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delayAmount);
            holder.timeReported = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeReported);
            holder.dateReported = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateReported);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Wait wait = waits.get(position);
        holder.checkpointName.setText(wait.getName());
        holder.delayAmount.setText(wait.getDelayInMinutes());
        holder.timeReported.setText(wait.getTimeLabel());
        holder.dateReported.setText(wait.getDateLabel());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView checkpointName;
        TextView delayAmount;
        TextView timeReported;
        TextView dateReported;
    }
}
```

**12/14/14 Update: General implementation background.**

At launch the App class starts WaitAsyncTask, which parses remote XML to fill its ArrayList waits. I'll access these waits in a few places so this way I keep them global.

WaitFragment, working with WaitAdapter, displays waits in a ListView and listens for changes to waits. User's can post waits to the web service via an AlertDialog. A successful response executes WaitAsyncTask again, updating the waits object, triggering a WaitFragment refresh().

Console logs and the web service confirm this flow of control and that waits gets updated. If I leave WaitFragment then return, it shows the updated waits. The code posted with comments #1-6 are what I've tried inside of the refresh() to update the ListView.

I use this general approach with other data and fragments in this app and their UIs refresh as intended, but none are listViews. I'm not sure I could post more source without redacting most of it but I'll share my findings once I get it working. I haven't had trouble with ListView before, but it'll be something embarrassing for sure. Thanks to everyone who took a little time :)

Comment: It may be that your arraylist `waits` is not get update with new data.

Comment: Are you filtering the adapter at any point?

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya I can confirm via console logs that the arrayList is getting updated.

Comment: @JaySoyer The adapter isn't filtered in any way.

Comment: Can you post more code showing where those methods to refresh the `ListView` are being invoked? Somethings going on but we need more code to help figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method in Adapter class to update/refresh the listview as follows,

```
  public class WaitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Wait> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Wait> waits;

    public WaitAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Wait> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_wait, data);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        waits = data;
    }   

       /**
        * Update content
        */
        public void updateListContent(ArrayList<Wait> data)
        {
        waits = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     }
```

In your acivity class, just call this adapter method to update the content. Refer the below code

Note:Dont clear the array content of the adapter.

```
  //Dont clear the arraylist of adapter
  adapter.updateListContent(App.getWaits());
```

This may help you.

Comment: This didn't help but I appreciate your take on it.